# Solving the trig inequality $|\sin{x} + \cos{x}| > 1$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, trigonometry, inequality

$|\sin{x} + \cos{x} |> 1$
How to solve this kind of question? Is there any websites to learn trigonometry inequalities? My teacher only taught us the simple question but not the complicated one. Thank you.

Comment: The inequality in the title differs from the one in the body. You may want to fix that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**Hint:**

$$\sin x + \cos x = \sqrt{2}\sin \left(x + \frac{\pi}{4}\right)$$

So for your expression to be greater than $1$, is suffices to check in which intervals $$\left|\sin y \right| > \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$$

where $y = x + \frac{\pi}{4}$. This is not hard to do by looking at a graph of $\sin y$, remembering that $\sin y = \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}} \iff y = 2\pi k + \frac{\pi}{4}$ or $y = 2\pi k + \frac{3\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 5):

$$|\sin{x} + \cos{x} |> 1$$ Square this expression then you'll get $$\sin^2x +2 \sin(x) \cos(x) +\cos^2x >1 $$ Simplify $$1+\sin2x>1$$ or $$\sin2x>0$$ Now $\sin2x$ is just a sine function but which is $\pi$ periodic, then this function is positive for $$x+ \pi k $$ where $ 0<x <\pi/2$

[image]

Answer (score 2):

I am restricting to those $x$ when $\sin x$ and $\cos x$ are both positive.
Remember for a positive number less than $1$ its square root is bigger than itself.

Now $$\sin x + \cos x = \sin x +\sqrt{1-\sin ^2 x} > \sin x + (1 -\sin ^2 x ) $$

Note that the last term is $1 + \sin x (1-\sin x)> 1$.

Comment: How would this approach work if $\sin x\cdot\cos x<0$?

Comment: Haven't figured that out yet!

Comment: @TZakrevskiy: Omar Nagib has answered your doubt. The claim is false if $x>pi/2$. I checked with calclulator (radians) $\sin(2) + \cos (2)\approx 0.49315$

Answer (score 0):

There is an inequality that is very useful in this case: if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then $$|a\sin(x)+b\cos(x)|\leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}.$$

To prove this one can find use the Cauchy-Schwarz inequality : $$|a\sin x+b \cos x| = |(a,b)\cdot (\sin x,\cos x)|\leq \sqrt{a^2+b^2}\sqrt{\sin^2 x+\cos^2 x}=\sqrt{a^2+b^2}$$

You are being asked to solve $|\sin(x)-\cos(x)|<1$. What happens, for example, if you take $a=\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ and $b=-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}$ in the inequality proven above?